# c#: How do i track mouse-events on non-rectangular graphics drawn on a panel?

Tags: c#, drawing, mouseevent

How do i track mouse-events on non-rectangular graphics drawn on a panel?

When using rectangular graphics or graphics that can be contained within a rectangular bounding box, i just use Rectangle.Contains. What do i do with non-rectangular shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a GraphicsPath then you both draw it (Graphics.DrawPath) and do hit testing with GrapicsPath.IsVisible.  If the drawing is convoluted with overlapping layers of paint then you could draw to the screen as well as a back-bitmap.  With the latter using color values to indicate specific objects.  Hit test with GetPixel().

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Region to draw your graphics and hit test.
Hit test a point in a region: Region.IsVisible(PointF)

See http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/2D-Graphics/IsapointvisibletoaRegion.htm